# Webpack hide source mapping chunk js files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, lazy-loading

I've created an App that using React with Craco. I separated all javascript files based on the declared routes. So far, this scenario is perfectly fine and working without any issue. To my knowledge, this mapping goes to the index.html file, just like below:

```json
{
 "0": "37fff959",
 "1": "c010263f",
 "2": "32a9d313",
 "3": "2a0beaa1"
}
```

Is there a way to hide this mapping from index.html or any common js files without serverside rendering? I do not want unauthorized users to see these files or mapping. Another question would be how any specific route will know which js file has to load without mapping?